# Просмотр ошибки после обработки исключения

Tags: python

После обработки исключения в открывшемся окне появляется собственно ошибка вызвавшая исключение, но при повторном вызове этой ошибки в открывшемся окне пишется ещё и прошлая, а мне нужна только последняя, подскажите что сделать что бы печаталась только последняя ошибка вызвавшая исключение, а не все. Спасибо за ваше потраченное время

"""

```
except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError:
    window = Tk()
    window.title("not connected")
    lbl = Label(window, text=traceback.format_exc())
    lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)
    window.mainloop()
```

"""

что должно быть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

что получается после нескольких вызовов исключения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Так как мне нужна была только ошибка, а не её расположение, я сделала так:

```py
except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError as ae:
        window = Tk()
        window.title("not connected")
        lbl = Label(window, text=ae)
        lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)
        window.mainloop()
```